# how to hide a button after clicking it and calling a php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Why its not working ?
I want to hide a submit button after it is clicked and also run a php page in the background at the same time to insert the entry into the table. How both these functions can be accomplished at the same time ?

```js
function click(){
     $(".hide").hide();
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "onProfile.php",
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {data you want to send},
          success: function(data){
                
                   }
      });
      return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onClick="click()" class="hide" value="Submit">
```

Comment: And even use a preventdefault if you don't want the user to change page =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an id to your button called: `submit`. Then no need to add the `onclick`. (Or you can use the `$('.hide')` selector.)

```
<input type="submit" class="hide" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

After this, you can check the click:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "onProfile.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {data you want to send},
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean not working? http://jsfiddle.net/e558r7jj/ I commented out the ajax part, because on jsfiddle, there are no `onProfile.php` and the data is unknown for us.

Comment: So without sending data php page the button wont hide ?

Comment: I do not understand you. It's hiding when you click on it. If you want to hide only when the php returned with some data, just move the `$(this).hide();` into the success function. I removed the ajax on jsfiddle, because there aren't your php file.

Comment: I meant that even if the data is not sent to php...the button should hide...I'll try your above code..

Comment: If the button should hide in every case, then don't move that line.  I forget to add my jsfiddle" http://jsfiddle.net/omee71mc/

Answer (score 1):

The input element has a function `click` and is called instead of your click function, easiest solution is to change the name of your function.
A better solution would be to not use inline event handling

```
$(".hide").on('click', click);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(){
    $(button).hide();
}
```